# analytical solution of the convection-diffusion equation $u_t = -au_x + u_{xx}$

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

This is part 1 of problem 8 from the book "Computational Partial Differential equations Using MATLAB" by Jichun Li and Yi-Tung Chen:

[image]

Authors barely mention the method of separation of variables and that the solution is a linear combination of Fourier modes.
So, after a lot of reading from different sources, I got this:

Let $u(x,t)$ be the solution of the given pde, this is the equation I'm looking for.
Lets define the Fourier transform and its inverse for $u(x,t) as$:

$$U(w,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(x,t)e^{-iwx}dx$$
$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}U(w,t)e^{iwx}dw$$

Also I know that the fourier transform of $\frac{d^nu(x,t)}{(dx)^n}$ is $(iw)^nU(w,t)$.

Taking the fourier transform from both sides of the given pde:
$$\frac{dU(w,t)}{(dt)} = (-w^2 - aiw)U(w,t)$$
$$U(w,t) = U(w,0) e^{-(w^2 + aiw)t}$$

Replacing $U(w,0)$ with the function from the fourier transform:
$$U(w,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(x,0)e^{-iwx}dx) e^{-(w^2 + aiw)t}$$

Taking the inverse fourier transform:
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(x,0)dx) e^{-(w^2 + aiw)t}dw$$
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(x,0)dx)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(w^2 + aiw)t}dw$$

Completing squares to get the normal distribution function (I'm operating on the exponentials):
$$-(w^2 + aiw)t = -(w^2 + aiw + \frac{a^2}{2} - \frac{a^2}{2})t$$
$$= -(w^2 + aiw + \frac{a^2}{4})t - \frac{a^2t}{4}$$
$$= -(w - \frac{-ai}{2})^2t - \frac{a^2t}{4}$$

Puting the exponentials back to the original equation:
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(x,0)dx)e^{- \frac{a^2t}{4}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(w - \frac{-ai}{2})^2t}dw$$

$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4t\pi}}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(x,0)dx)e^{- \frac{a^2t}{4}}\frac{\sqrt{2t}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(w - \frac{-ai}{2})^2t}dw$$

$$u(x,t)=\frac{e^{- \frac{a^2t}{4}}}{\sqrt{4t\pi}}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(x,0)dx)$$

$$\frac{u(x,t)}{dx}=\frac{e^{- \frac{a^2t}{4}}}{\sqrt{4t\pi}}u(x,0)$$

Let $k(t)$ be the boundary value when $x=0$
$$u(x,t)=k(t)\frac{e^{- \frac{a^2t}{4}}}{\sqrt{4t\pi}}e^{x}$$

My solution does not look like the one given by the book. I don't know how to proceed from this point.

**Update:** Following the comment of Joey Zou, I got:

From the value of $U(x,t)$: 
$$U(w,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(x,0)e^{-iwx}dx) e^{-(w^2 + aiw)t}$$

I can consider $u(x,t)$ some function $f(y)$ because it doesn't depend of $t$:
$$U(w,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)e^{-iwy}dy) e^{-(w^2 + aiw)t}$$

Taking the inverse fourier transform:
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)dy)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-w^2t - aiwt-iwy+iwx}dw$$

**Update!** Thanks Winther for noticing my mistakes:

Completing squares to get the normal distribution function:
$$-w^2t - aiwt-iwy+iwx = -t[w^2 -(iwyt^{-1}-iwxt^{-1}-aiw) + (\frac{iyt^{-1}-ixt^{-1}-ai}{2})^2] + (\frac{iyt-ixt-ait}{2})^2$$

$$-w^2t - aiwt-iwy+iwx = -t[w^2 -(iwyt^{-1}-iwxt^{-1}-aiw) + (\frac{iyt^{-1}-ixt^{-1}-ai}{2})^2] - (\frac{yt-xt-at}{2})^2$$

Putting exponentials back to the equation:
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4t\pi}}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)dy)e^{- (\frac{yt-xt-at}{2})^2}\frac{\sqrt{2t}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(w - \frac{iyt^{-1}-ixt^{-1}-ai}{2})^2t}dw$$

$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4t\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)e^{- (\frac{yt-xt-at}{2})^2}dy$$

All I know is that $u(x, 0) = f(y)$ but I do not have more information about the $y$ variable. So I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: Well, to check if a proposed solution is actually a solution of a PDE, all you need to do is to take the appropriate derivatives, plug them into the equation, and see if things work out. I think that's all the exercise is asking you to do.

Comment: Now, in your attempt to directly solve the equation, in taking the inverse Fourier transform, you used $x$ both as an actual variable on the LHS and as a dummy variable in the integral on the RHS--that's not good! And I think it lead to some of your confusion too, since it seemed you ``cancelled'' the $e^{iwx}$ terms. Consider, in your equation for the Fourier transform $U(w,t)$, using a different variable (say $y$) as your dummy variable of integration before plugging it into the inverse Fourier formula, and see if anything works out.

Comment: It does not make sense to get a final result that depends on $w$ - the variable you were integrating over in the previous step. Also what is the question here: to solve the question given in the picture or how to derive the most general form for the solution?

Comment: @Winther you're right! My mind got blurry to this point, I'm fixing this. Also, the question is about finding the general form for the solution

Comment: If you take $u(x,t) = v(x,t) e^{\frac{ax}{2} - \frac{a^2t}{4}}$ then $v$ satisfy $v_t = v_{xx}$ which is the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Homogeneous_heat_equation) which has the solution 

$$v(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty v(y,0) e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}{\rm d}y$$

so the expression you should end up with is something like

$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(y,0) e^{\frac{a(x-y)}{2}-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}-\frac{a^2t}{4}}{\rm d}y$$

Comment: @Winther yes, It does look something like that!